# TabLayoutPanel can't see content of tabs

Tags: gwt

Code:

```
TabLayoutPanel tlpContent = new TabLayoutPanel(100, Unit.PX);
tlpContent.add(new Image("tab1"),"TAB1");
tlpContent.add(new Image("tab2"),"TAB2");
tlpContent.add(new Image("tab3"),"TAB3");

RootPanel contentSlot = RootPanel.get("content");
   if (contentSlot!=null){
       contentSlot.add(tlpContent);
}
```

I don't see "tab1" or "tab2" or "tab3" when I click on headline "TAB1"...
I look at code html page "tab1" "tab2" "tab3" is there.

html page: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Your code snippet does not have the brackets balanced.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing layout with non-layout panels. This is not going to work well. You can:

- use a `TabPanel` (the non-layout version);
- set the `TabLayoutPanel` size explicitly;
- use the `RootLayoutPanel` (but, remember, it will wrap the whole page, not just the `content` element).

See [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Recipes), for the relevant documentation.

Comment: Additionally, you can put the `TabLayoutPanel` inside any `ProvidesResize` like another Layout Panel, though in almost all cases that panel must itself be in another layout panel. The main exception to this is `RootLayoutPanel` as you noted, which takes all available browser space, and `ResizeLayoutPanel` which will check to see when its size changes and notify the child.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Height to `TabLayoutPanel`.
`tlpContent.setHeight("300px")` use only px - to set height and check with firebug and analyse code how it's working.

And check whether you included CSS properly.